# Camunda: Configure/setup MS SQL server database for rest api

Tags: sql-server, rest, camunda

By default, camunda rest api uses H2 database. 
I'm unable to locate the file where I can configure the rest api to use Microsoft SQL Server.

Apologies for not being much clear as I am new to camunda.

Comment: You use JBoss/Wildfly?

Comment: I'm using Tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find information's about configure the JDBC connections in the Camunda installation Guide.

For Example for [Tomcat](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/installation/full/tomcat/manual/#configure-a-jdbc-resource) (you have to simply edit the `driverClassName`, `url` and the credentials).

> To configure a JDBC Resource you have to edit the file
>   $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml. This could look like the following
>   example for an H2 database:

```
<Server>
  ...
  <GlobalNamingResources>
    ...
    <Resource name="jdbc/ProcessEngine"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              uniqueResourceName="process-engine"
              driverClassName="org.h2.Driver"
              url="jdbc:h2:./camunda-h2-dbs/process-engine;MVCC=TRUE;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0"
              username="sa"
              password=""
              maxActive="20"
              minIdle="5" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
</Server>
```

For [JBoss](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/installation/full/jboss/manual/#required-setup-for-jboss-as-7-jboss-eap-6) or [Wildfly](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.6/installation/full/jboss/manual/#required-setup-for-wildfly-jboss-eap-7) you have to edit the `standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`:

Add a datasource and driver tag, which could like the [following](https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/HowToSetADatasourceConnectionToMSSQLServer), to the datasources.

```
<datasource jta="true" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true"
                jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ProcessEngine"
                pool-name="ProcessEngine">
    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER_NAME:SERVER_PORT;databaseName=DB_NAME</connection-url>
    <driver>sqlserver2008</driver>
    <security>
        <user-name>USERNAME</user-name>
        <password>PASSWORD</password>
    </security>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>5</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>50</max-pool-size>
        <prefill>false</prefill>
        <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
    </pool>
    <validation>
        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mssql.MSSQLValidConnectionChecker"></valid-connection-checker>
    </validation>
</datasource>
<drivers>
    <driver name="sqlserver2008" module="com.microsoft">
        <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
    </driver>
</drivers>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zelldon :)

Comment: I am using tomcat prepackaged .zip.

Comment: I have changed my server.xml to

`<Resource name="jdbc/ProcessEngine"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
              factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
              uniqueResourceName="Camunda"
              driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
              url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433/Camunda"
              defaultTransactionIsolation="READ_COMMITTED"
              username="sa"  
              password="mypassword"
              maxActive="20"
              minIdle="5" />`

Comment: I have successfully created the database with the name Camunda using the mssql scripts.
and it is not working.

Comment: Please create a new question so we can help on your current challange